# How to add a splashscreen for iPhone to a App made from iPad to Universal

Tags: iphone, default, splash-screen, ios-universal-app

I want to add a splashscreen within an App that is an iPad-App currently. I succeeding with using different app icons (both for iPhone and iPad), but the splashscreen. Now called "Default-Portrait~iphone.png" but the splashscreen is not being showed. Anyone got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just name the file Default.png (and Default@2x.png) and the iPhone version will use it. iPhone doesn't support multiple Default.png orientations like iPad does.

Comment: Thanks, changing the name did the job.